# Why can’t CnosDB partially update Tag?

Tags: cnosdb

I noticed that cnosdb supports updating Tags, but this seems to only change them all at once.

I have the following data, how can I update the Tag where Field = 1.

| Tag | Field |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

The content of this section seems to be still in development